# Its there a way to use Firebird/Ibase with Doctrine in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, firebird

**Configuration of doctrine in Zend Framework:**
This is the configuration to use mysql driver but i want tu use the PDO database driver for ibase.

```
   <?php
    return array(
       'doctrine' => array(
            'connection' => array(
                'orm_default' => array(
                    'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',    
                    'params' => array(
                            'driver_options' => array(
                                  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'
                            ),
                    ),

                ),
            )
    ));  
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dbal Doctrine driver for firebird is a work in progress not yet merged on github

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-95

I have requested the patch and it will be integrated soon

On the Zend Framework side it should be possible to use the pdo addapter without dbal (unsupported yet)

https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.db.adapter.html#zend-db-adapter

Answer (score 3):

```
Thanks!

Looks like meanwhile i can use the PDO for Ibase with a Zend Adapter

return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'PDO_FIREBIRD',
        'database' => 'localhost:C:\Base.FDB',
        'username' => 'SYSDBA',
        'password' => 'masterkey',
    ),
);
```